# How to auto pagebreak the PDFsharp document?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

I am trying to generate a PDF document from C# WPF control.
Here is my [image: result].

The result comes out with half of my object, how to auto page-break the page?
Below is my code:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => fixedDoc = new FixedDocument()));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => fixedDoc1 = new FixedDocument()));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => pageContent = new PageContent()));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => pageContent1 = new PageContent()));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => fixedPage = new FixedPage()));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => fixedPage1 = new FixedPage()));

        var visual = Child as UIElement;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => (Content).Children.Remove(visual)));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => fixedPage.Children.Clear()));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => fixedPage.Children.Add(visual)));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage)));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent)));

        // write to PDF file
        string tempFilename = "temp.Xps";
        File.Delete(tempFilename);
        XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(tempFilename, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => xw.Write(fixedDoc)));
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => xpsd.Close()));
        filename = filepath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "-" + title_ + ".pdf";
        PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(tempFilename, filename, 1);

        var visual2 = Child2 as UIElement;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => (Content).Children.Remove(visual2)));
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => fixedPage1.Children.Clear()));
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => fixedPage1.Children.Add(visual2)));
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent1).AddChild(fixedPage1)));
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => fixedDoc1.Pages.Add(pageContent1)));

        // write to PDF file
        string tempFilename2 = "temp2.Xps";
        File.Delete(tempFilename2);
        XpsDocument xpsd2 = new XpsDocument(tempFilename2, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        XpsDocumentWriter xw2 = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd2);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => xw2.Write(fixedDoc1)));
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => xpsd2.Close()));
        filename2 = filepath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "-" + title_ + ".pdf";
        PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(tempFilename2, filename2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFsharp does not do automatic page breaks.

I'd suggest to do what others do with their charts: only show the big ones (10, 20, 30 or so) and summarise the really small ones as "others". This way the legend will fit on one page and you avoid having "zero width" pie pieces in your chart.

This is not really an answer to your question, but it is a workaround that also complies with good practices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for some reason, I need to show all of the data.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with the PDFsharp XPS converter, but would it be an option to increase the size of the PDF page so that the whole diagram fits on a single page, showing all items? In a second step it would be possible to show this oversize page on a series if standard pages (if you need that)

Comment: if I increase the page size then I can't print it in A4 size, that's why I need the auto-pagebreak or some similar function. What do you mean showing the page on series?

Comment: If you increase the page size then you can do the page breaks in a separate loop - or use Adobe Reader to print large pages on several A4 pages.